# Python - display excel database in a grid - part 2

Tags: python, excel, pygame, grid-layout

My aim is to create a grid that looks like the following http://i49.tinypic.com/f39hxv.png, where each number represents the number of 'preperation flakes' found in each square (see data snippet below)

The code so far is as follows:

```
import csv
import os

import pygame

# the functions for display
def disp(phrase,loc,screen):   # function to display phrase at loc on surface.
    s = font.render(phrase, True, (255,255,255))
    screen.blit(s, loc) #

def text_display_csv(filename,surface):
    '''Display .csv file contents on surface'''
    f = csv.reader(open("Flint catalogue v1.7 4 Feb 13 2013.csv")) # open the csv file      in one line!

    for row in f:
        y = f.line_num                # assign y as Row no.
        for x,item in enumerate(row): # Get column number(x) and item
            disp(item, (64*x+10,64*y+10), surface) # display item



pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier",10) # font initialisation
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,1200))


filename = 'the .csv file'
text_display_csv(filename,screen) # text is displayed
pygame.display.update() # screen updated

# Main loop, does nothing! :)
running = True
while running:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
             pygame.quit()
             break
    if not running:
        break
```

I would like the grid to look a bit like this (but my trouble is putting data from the database into this array):

```
import csv
import os



import pygame

# Define some colors
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
green    = (   0, 255,   0)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)

# This sets the width and height of each grid location
width=20
height=20

# This sets the margin between each cell
margin=5

# Create a 2 dimensional array. A two dimesional
# array is simply a list of lists.
grid=[]
for row in range(10):
    # Add an empty array that will hold each cell
    # in this row
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(10):
        grid[row].append(0) # Append a cell

# Set row 1, cell 5 to one. (Remember rows and
# column numbers start at zero.)
grid[1][5] = 1
grid[1][6] = 2 
# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
 size=[255,255]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while done==False:

     # Set the screen background
       screen.fill(black)

    # Draw the grid
      for row in range(10):
          for column in range(10):
              color = white
              if row[4]in c == 1:
                 color = green
               pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[(margin+width)*column+margin,        (margin+height)*row+margin,width,height])

     # Limit to 20 frames per second
      clock.tick(20)

     # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
      pygame.display.flip()

      pygame.quit()
```

The data is a s follows:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2rdgn02&s=6

So to sum up. i would like different 'classifications' (see data) to be displayed in the grid like the pic at the start.

Thanks for the help

Tom

Comment: Where is the data in your wanted output image in your csv ? No offence intended but Please be more clear. What do you need? Do you want to sort the data by the P(classification column) ? And did you see my comment on the previous question?

Comment: sorry i havent replied was at work. right what i want is for the classifications (column p) to be displayed in their respective grid squares (column s). the grid square in column s being the same as on the 6x6 grid i want to make. please say if this isnt clear

Comment: So the [x][y] cells don't match the locations of the cells on screen? If you want to see an example using 2d arrays via `numpy` check out map.py http://code.google.com/p/ninmonkey/source/browse/#hg%2Fexamples%2Fmaptiles_numpy

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code,
That is your code other than 10 chars max (except comments and removals), but causes **Big** changes.

```py
import pygame,csv

def disp(phrase,loc,screen): 
    s = font.render(phrase, True, (255,255,255))
    screen.blit(s, loc)

# not needed

def text_display_csv(filename,surface):
    '''Display .csv file contents on surface'''
    f = csv.reader(open(filename))

    for row in f:
        y = f.line_num                
        for x,item in enumerate(row):
            disp(item, (60*x+10,12*y-2), surface) # changed y distance

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier",10) # Changed font size
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480)) # changed window size

filename = "Flint catalogue v1.7 4 Feb 13 2013.csv"
text_display_csv(filename,screen) 
pygame.display.update()

# Main loop, does nothing! :)
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            break
    if not running:
        break
```

---

**Update 1**
Ok, I see.
So, you want to display data in P at Grid no S...

Here's the code for that too. Just change `text_display_csv` to this,

```py
def text_display_csv(filename,surface):
    '''Display .csv file contents on surface, after processing'''
    f = csv.reader(open(filename))
    # The Processing
    data = {}
    for row in f:
        y = f.line_num
        if len(row) >= 19:
            # See if S contains a number,
            # if No: Print the msg
            # else: add to dict, in form of S:P
            try:
                val = int(row[18]) # S is the 19th column
            except ValueError:
                print "Skipped row no",y,"as column S doesn't contain number"
                continue
            else: # if a number, add to the dict
                data[val] = row[15] # P is the 16th column
    print "File Loaded"
    # the display part
    width = 6
    for loc in data:
        item = data[loc] # get item (string to display)
        y = loc//width   # column
        x = loc % width  # row
        disp(item, (60*x +10,30*y +10), surface)
```

What's Happening here:

1. Load `.csv`
2. If a row has items till at least `S` column,

   - If value at `S` is a number, get it's integer value.
     Then add information to a dictionary in the form of `S : P`, Where

     - `S` is the integer
     - `P` the string/value at column `P`.
   - Otherwise print a msg, and move on to the next row(if any)
3. Display Data at their respective places.

Now the only problem is that the numbers have to start with zero.
To overcome that, Just add

```py
loc += 1
```

Before

```py
y = loc//width
```

Your grid lines can be drawn using `pygame.draw.line`, you can figure that out.

Comment: is there away of attaching files here?

Comment: @TomLawrence I saw your comment (the reply to my comment on the question), and added an update. Also, What do you mean by attaching files?